# How do you make Spring fail fast when using placeholders with @ConfiguraitonProperties and an environment variable is not set?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, configuration-files

When using placeholders to externalise configuration in an `application.yaml` file, and an associated properties class, ***how do you make sure Spring fails during startup when it can't resolve a placeholder***, instead of just using the placeholder itself as the verbatim value?

For example, given this `application.yaml` file:

```
example.key: ${MY_ENV_VAR}
```

and this properties POJO:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="example")
public class AcmeProperties {
  public String key;
  // Getters, setters, constructors omitted... 
}
```

if `MY_ENV_VAR` is not set on the system, ***how do you make Spring throw an exception at startup***, instead of setting `key` to *literally* `${MY_ENV_VAR}`?

Note, Spring doesn't return an empty String, which we could force by defining a default with `${MY_ENV_VAR:defaultValue}`, or `null` ([SpEL is not evaluated in `@ConfigurationProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-vs-value), so this can not be defined as the default, and the behaviour of `System.getenv("MY_ENV_VAR")` returning `null` in the case of an undefined environment variable isn't mirrored), it literally just uses the placeholder as the value. We'd rather Spring stopped launching the app altogether instead, for all properties in `AcmeProperties`. Just using `@Validated` with Hibernate Validator on the classpath doesn't do it, neither does `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="example", ignoreInvalidFields=false)` (which is the [default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html#ignoreInvalidFields--) anyway).

A manual check for the value containing `${...}` could of course be added to all `String` properties in the POJO, but this is more error-prone, and would also not work if the actual environment variable was set to a string containing that character sequence. Is there a way to check if the placeholder can be resolved, instead of if the value after resolution is complete?

Comment: `${...}` isn't SpEL but a value expression those are different things, SpEL expression start with `#{` not `${`. So `${MY_ENV_VAR:}` should work to assign a default value (in fact I used that in many cases to provide a default with the possibility to override!). Also blowing up when not being able to resolve placeholders is actually the default, so not sure why it is not work. Have you tried an older version of Spring Boot (assuming you are on 2.2.0 here!).

Comment: The default value for value expressions works indeed, as I mentioned above. I just wanted to note that SpEL is explicitly not supported, so you can't use it to hack a `null` as a default in there. A colleague just stumbled upon [this line](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/bind/PropertySourcesPlaceholdersResolver.java#L51), which is the reason why it doesn't seem to work; the flag whether to check or not seems to be hardcoded to `false`...

Comment: Apart from adding `@Validated` to the `AcmeProperties` class, have you added other validation annotations to the attributes as well? `@NotNull` for example.

Comment: As I pointed out, I'd rather avoid that, as it's error-prone (easy to forget an annotation), and not the same to check the value after resolution vs the actual presence of the environment variable. (Also, with the way it currently works, the property will never be `null`, I think? Unless an empty default String would be turned into `null`.)

Comment: There is a bug/feature request ticket over at github for this now: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18816

Answer (score 0):

You can have a custom validator which could look like:

```
object UnresolvedPropertiesValidator : Validator {

    override fun supports(clazz: Class<*>): Boolean {
        return clazz == String::class.java
    }

    override fun validate(target: Any, errors: Errors) {
        val stringVal = target as String
        if (stringVal.startsWith(SystemPropertyUtils.PLACEHOLDER_PREFIX) && stringVal.endsWith(SystemPropertyUtils.PLACEHOLDER_SUFFIX)) {
            errors.reject(
                "prop.validation",
                "Could not resolve placeholder $target"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

And then create a bean with the name `configurationPropertiesValidator`:

```
class UnresolvedPropertiesValidatorAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun configurationPropertiesValidator(): UnresolvedPropertiesValidator {
        return UnresolvedPropertiesValidator
    }
}
```

As you can see from these https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/24a52aa66ddb92cd14acb2b41d9f55b957a44829/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/EnableConfigurationProperties.java#L47
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/9630f853be3183f4872428e2e65b6ef4be7a9b7a/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java#L105,
the validator with the name above will be applied after resolving the prop, and it simply ensures the final value doesn't start with `${` and end with `}`.

This works for us. But hopefully, the issue will be resolved soon, and we will remove this workaround.